# Binary search over a huge file with unknown line length

Tags: python, database, io, binary-search, large-files

I'm working with huge data CSV file. Each file contains milions of record , each record has a key. The records are sorted by thier key. I dont want to go over the whole file when searching for certian data.
I've seen this solution : [Reading Huge File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744256/reading-huge-file-in-python)

But it suggests that you use the same length of lines on the file - which is not supported in my case.

I thought about adding a padding to each line and then keeping a fixed line length , but I'd like to know if there is a better way to do it.

I'm working with python

Comment: @Mat- not an option right now. I've got a very limited deadline , and not enough time to create database from that data.

Comment: Do the binary search on byte level and after the seek find the nearest newline.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5942463/616486 sqlite seems to have an automatic csv import option.

Comment: Nobody's binary search works properly first time. You could have had a database solution up and running by now. How many different large files do you have? What is a typical number of records? What is a typical file size in GB? Is the key a number or a string?

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to have a fixed width record because you don't have to do a record-oriented search. Instead you can just do a byte-oriented search and make sure that you realign to keys whenever you do a seek. Here's a (probably buggy) example of how to modify the solution you linked to from record-oriented to byte-oriented:

```
bytes = 24935502 # number of entries
for i, search in enumerate(list): # list contains the list of search keys
  left, right = 0, bytes - 1 
  key = None
  while key != search and left <= right:
    mid = (left + right) / 2
    fin.seek(mid)
    # now realign to a record
    if mid:
        fin.readline()
    key, value = map(int, fin.readline().split())
    if search > key:
      left = mid + 1
    else:
      right = mid - 1
  if key != search:
    value = None # for when search key is not found
  search.result = value # store the result of the search
```

Answer (score 2):

To resolve it, you also can use binary search, but you need to change it a bit:

1. Get the file size.
2. Seek to the middle of size, with File.seek.
3. And search the first EOL character. Then you find a new line.
4. Check this line's key and if not what you want, update size and go to 2.

Here is a sample code:

```
fp = open('your file')
fp.seek(0, 2)
begin = 0
end = fp.tell()

while (begin < end):
    fp.seek((end + begin) / 2, 0)
    fp.readline()
    line_key = get_key(fp.readline())
    if (key == line_key):
        pass # find what you want
    elif (key > line_key):
        begin = fp.tell()
    else:
        end = fp.tell()
```

Maybe the code has bugs. Verify yourself. And please check the performance if you really want a fastest way.

Comment: It seems never find the first line.

Answer (score 1):

The answer on the referenced question that says binary search only works with fixed-length records is wrong.  And you don't need to do a search at all, since you have multiple items to look up.  Just walk through the entire file one line at a time, build a dictionary of `key:offset` for each line, and then for each of your search items jump to the record of interest using `os.lseek` on the offset corresponding to each key.

Of course, if you don't want to read the entire file even once, you'll have to do a binary search.  But if building the index can be amortized over several lookups, perhaps saving the index if you only do one lookup per day, then a search is unnecessary.