# How to break a file into two and then search only through the second half?

Tags: python, parsing, io

How does one break a file into two parts depending on a key word...and then parse through that file for the expression 'chain "edt_'?

Comment: I think you are looking for this. [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369175/binary-search-over-a-huge-file-with-unknown-line-length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example text file (named **temp.txt**):

```
hello 10 20 30
goodbye 20 30 40
keyword 5 6 7
chain "edt_ 0 1 2
rubbish 2 3 4
more 6 7 8
test 1 2 3
```

If we want to split the file when we find **keyword**, and then search for the expression **chain "edt_**, this is one way to do it:

```
# Read the file
with open('temp.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# Strip out newline char
data = [i.strip('\n') for i in data]

# Look for keyword
kwLoc = [i.find('keyword') for i in data].index(0)

print 'Keyword found on line {0} - splitting file.'.format(kwLoc)

# Split the file
partOne = data[:kwLoc]
partTwo = data[kwLoc:]

# Optionally save each file
with open('temp_1.txt','w') as f:
    for row in partOne:
        f.writelines(row)
        f.write('\n')

with open('temp_2.txt','w') as f:
    for row in partTwo:
        f.writelines(row)
        f.write('\n')

# Now search the file for the expression - returning the row where it occurs

exLoc = [i.find('chain "edt_')>0 for i in partTwo].index(True)


print 'Found expression chain "edt on row {0}.'.format(exLoc)
```

Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: Thanks so much, Robbie. :)

I did run into one error though:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split_file.py", line 32, in <module>
    exLoc = [i.find('chain "edt_') for i in partTwo].index(0)
ValueError: 0 is not in list

Comment: The error is saying there are no lines with the string 'chain "edt' in it. Is this what's happening?

Comment: No, I just checked and found this in the second file produced by the script:

 chain "edt_disppipebpar1_channel1" = "0

Comment: Okay - I'm not at my computer at the moment but will check it out soon and edit my answer

Comment: Okay check out the new code (just changed the line with exLoc = ...)

Comment: Perfect! =) Thank you again, Robbie!

Comment: Hey Robbie...for this line:

    kwLoc = [i.find('measure') for i in data].index(0)

How might you make it search backwards? IE: from the end of the file to the beginning of the file?